# Is it possible to define a custom parser and AST for quotations in F#?

Tags: f#, dsl

Is it possible to define a custom parser and AST for quotations in F#?  Specifically, the code

```ml
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
let e = <@ 1+1 @>
```

Generates

```ml
val e : Expr<int> = Call (None, op_Addition, [Value (1), Value (1)])
```

I would like to instead do two things.  One, I would like to generate my own AST.  For example

```ml
val it : Expr = Add(Num 1,Num 1)
```

Two, I would like to define my own parser and not use F# syntax.  For example, it would be nice to write something like

```ml
let e = <@ 1++1 @>
```

Certainly, if I don't care about the syntax, I could define a program transformation from the F# syntax tree to my own syntax tree.  I do not want to do that; I want to use a custom parser.

For some background, I would like to use quotations and antiquotations to generate an AST for some DSL.  Basically, I would like to have the following

```ml
let e1 = <@ 1 @>
let e2 = <@ %e1 + 2 @>
```

generate `Add(Num 1,Num 2)` and not be beholden to F# syntax.

By the way, though a very different language now, the above is possible in OCaml with camlp4, so it seems feasible, but I'm not sure if there are any F# restrictions that prevent this.

## Edit 1

@tomas-petricek answered my immediate question, but what I'm looking for is more in line with @mydogisbox.  It looks like embedded languages are done differently in F# than in OCaml or Haskell and I didn't know that.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: F# is a Turing-capable programming language.  You build a parser in it, for anything which is reasonably parseable.  Are you asking us to build a parser for you?

Comment: Certainly, I could define some function that reads in a string and mostly does what I want to produce an AST.  However, putting antiquotations into this is a pain in the ass.  The most straight forward way to do this is like printf where we have special tags %d and %f, but then the argument is separated from the placeholder.  Since F# already has a quotation system, I would like to use this and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You ask if it is possible to write a parser.  It is.  What's left to do here?  Antiquotations is just more syntax; why is it an issue?   Maybe what you mean, "is is possible to write a parser that hooks into F# syntax"?  That I don't know.  Maybe you are insisting that your parser use F# (parsing) machinery for antiquote; that seems like it might be pretty hard because there is no reason to believe it will integrate well with the parser machinery you build.

Comment: The specific question above was not whether it was possible to generate a parser, but whether or not it's possible to integrate a custom parser into the quotation system in F#.  This is a common thing to do and useful for many reasons.  In OCaml, this is accomplished through camlp4 and the syntax `let foo = <myexpr:< parsers + are + $e$ >>`.  In Haskell, this is accomplished through Template Haskell and the syntax `let foo = [myexpr| parsers + are + $e |]`.  Good quotations tools provide the developer stuff like location information to provide sane errors (_loc in calmp4). This has been done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that can be wrapped in F# quotations is limited to valid F# syntax only. However, you can use it in quite flexible way - this can contain any functions or custom operators you wish. So, if you want `++`, you can define it (even without implementation):

```
let (++) a b = a + b
```

Quoted code is always represented as F# quotation (the `Expr` type), but you can translate that to any structure you need. For example, you can define a discriminated union:

```
type Expr = 
  | Add of Expr * Expr
  | SuperAdd of Expr * Expr
  | Num of int
```

And write a translation function that turns quotation into your `Expr`:

open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

```
let rec translate = function
  | DerivedPatterns.SpecificCall <@ (++) @> (_, _, [e1; e2]) -> 
      SuperAdd(translate e1, translate e2)
  | DerivedPatterns.SpecificCall <@ (+) @> (_, _, [e1; e2]) -> 
      Add(translate e1, translate e2)
  | Patterns.Value(n, t) when t = typeof<int> -> 
      Num(n :?> int)
  | _ -> failwith "Not supported"
```

Now, running this:

```
translate <@ 1 ++ (1 + 2) @>
```

...returns `SuperAdd (Num 1,Add (Num 1,Num 2))`.

The power of F# quotations is that they let you reinterpret standard F# code, so putting arbitrary syntax there would be against the principle. But you can always put custom constructs in a string and write a custom parser - using FParsec, FsLex/FsYacc, active patterns or other tools...

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to have compile-time safely for a custom language like you're wanting, but I think you're focusing on the wrong language feature.  Take a look at the [`FSharp.Data.SQLClient`](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/).  It's an F# type provider which statically analyzes a sql query (i.e. improperly formatted sql is a compile error) and executes it at runtime.  In other words, do this using a type provider rather than quotations.

Comment: I hadn't heard about this before and it looks like it's the F# way to embed languages.  Thanks for the pointer!